# Resolving an env variable using another env variable in .env file

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, environment-variables, .env

Can you use an env variable defined in a `.env` file to resolve the value of another env variable using a bash command?

Content of the `.env` file:

```
AWS_PROFILE=my-profile
AWS_ACCOUNT_ID=$(aws sts get-caller-identity --profile $AWS_PROFILE --query "Account" --output text)
```

Comment: Yes you can, you may need to source the `.env.` file in your shell script

Comment: What exactly works depends on what exactly does what exactly with the `.env` file. If the consumer only reads it as a static text file then you have to come up with a different approach; perhaps generate the `.env` file from a template with a tool like `envsubst`.

Comment: I don't unerstand what you mean by _to resolve .... using bash command_. In the code you posted, the value of the variable `AWS_ACCOUNT_ID` is calculated based on variable `AWS_PROFILE`.

Comment: @tripleee : Maybe it should be pointed out, that `envsubst` - which of course **is** a useful tool here - relies on substituting _environment_ variables. There is nothing in the OPs code which would suggest that the variables defined here are in the environment.